# Split column in two using '-' as delimiter

Tags: python

I would like to split a column in two, with a given delimiter. Excel file does not have a header in the columns. Example input and output files and are in the screenshots below:

Input:

[image]

Output:

[image]

Comment: Help us help you - please share a sample input and the output you're trying to get for it.

Answer (score 0):

You can follow the below steps and modify to suit your needs:

My original dataframe looks like this:

> `df1.head()`

```
District    Population  Ratio
0   Hampshire   25000   1.56
1   Dorset  500000  7.34
2   Wiltshire   735298  3.67
3   Worcestershire  12653   8.23
```

Since Ratio is a numeric column, you need to make it into string using:

> `df1['Ratio'] = df1['Ratio'].apply(str)`

Once the column is string, you can split it as per your need using:

> `df1['Decimal'] = df1['Ratio'].str.split('.').str[1]`
>   `df1['Ratio'] = df1['Ratio'].str.split('.').str[0]`

Final Dataframe looks like this where values are separated with respect to delimiter:

> `df1.head()`

```
District    Population  Ratio   Decimal
0   Hampshire   25000   1   56
1   Dorset  500000  7   34
2   Wiltshire   735298  3   67
3   Worcestershire  12653   8   23
```